# Evaluating $\frac{1}{f} \circ g$

Tags: functions

This may be a very easy question, suppose $f$ and $g$ are some arbitrary simple polynomial functions. When trying to evaluate $\frac{1}{f} \circ g$ ...

$$\frac{1}{f} \circ g = f^{-1} \circ g$$

Which could be written as:

$$f^{-1}(g(x))$$

Is this incorrect? If so, how would you handle the $\frac{1}{f}$ properly? I thought doing such a thing would yield something like:

$$(f)^{-1} \circ g$$

Where I would be lost at how to apply this from here.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Let $f: \mathbb{R}_{ \geq 0} \to \mathbb{R}$ by $f(x) = x^2$. Here we have that;

$$f^{-1}(x) = \sqrt{x} \not = \frac{1}{x^2}$$

what I am trying to say is that $\ f^{-1} \not = \frac{1}{f}$ in general.